# Change out page content at interval based on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to create somewhat of a 'slide changeout' functionality with a CMS I have that displays static page content. Rather than rotate URLs, I want to just change out the content of the page after a duration of time.

I have this working where I use a JSON object and through if/else statements determine which Html to use and which content( coming from the JSON) to use. I'm wondering if there's a way to cycle through each element of the JSON object for a certain amount of time?

Using this JSON:

```
[ { "pageID": "93",
   "page_type_id": "2",
   "display_id": "2",
   "slide_order": null,
   "duration": "74",
   "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
   "panel_id": "86",
   "panel_type_id": "2",
   "cont_id": "138",
   "contID": "138",
   "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" },
 { "pageID": "93",
   "page_type_id": "2",
   "display_id": "2",
   "slide_order": null,
   "duration": "74",
   "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
   "panel_id": "87",
   "panel_type_id": "3",
   "cont_id": "139",
   "contID": "139",
   "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>" 
 }]
```

It successfully loads the 2 content elements into the appropriate divs and the logic works. Here's the question though:

If I had a third element with pageID 94 and different content, and say I wanted to show content for page 93 for 15 seconds, then after 15 seconds I want to change it out and hide it/ show content for page 94 and so on.

Would this be feasible?

Example with current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let obj = <?php echo $showDisplays; ?>;
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumnQtr = document.getElementById('leftColumnQtr');
var rightColumnQtrHalf = document.getElementById('rightColumnQtrHalf');
var rightColumnQtr = document.getElementById('rightColumnQtr');
var leftColumnQtrHalf = document.getElementById('leftColumnQtrHalf');

for (var key in obj){
if(obj[key].page_type_id == 2){

    fullColumn.style.display = "none";
    leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
    rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
    leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
    rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";


    if(obj[key].panel_type_id == 2){

        leftContent.innerHTML = obj[key].content;

    }else if(obj[key].panel_type_id == 3){

        rightContent.innerHTML = obj[key].content;
    }

}

console.log(obj);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` / `setTimeout` will get you part of the way there.

Comment: `setInterval()` is supported by every browser, and takes 2 arguments. the first is a function with some commands to run, and the second is the amount of time to wait before running the function again... and again... and again...  `SetInterval(() => { /*  do some javascript here */ }, 1500)`

Comment: @TJBlackman so within my loop currently, could I set this to a function and make that function what I'm doing with my if/else? And then instead of a hard coded time I could set the 'duration' value of the current element as my time?

Comment: If either of you can put even some guided logic or sudo code as an answer I will gladly accept it and be incredibly appreciative. I'm still getting my feet wet with JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
        // parse json into actual array
        // use a counter to keep track of which object we show data for
        // with each iteration of setInterval:
        //      get reference to current item, 
        //      select some DOM elements, 
        //      update HTML, repeat
        //      if on last item, go back to item 0

        const json = JSON.parse(put_json_here);
        let counter = 0; 

        setInterval(() => {
            const currentJSONObject = json[counter]; 

            fullColumn.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtrHalf.style.display = "none";
            leftColumnQtr.style.display = "none";
            rightColumnQtr.style.display = "none";


            if (currentJSONObject.panel_type_id == 2){
                leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONObject.content;
            } else if (currentJSONObject.panel_type_id == 3){
                rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONObject.content;
            }

            counter += 1; 
            if (counter === json.length){
                counter = 0; 
            }

        }, 15000)
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is starting to make sense now. If I have other if/else statements based on other panel_types, it would all still work the same? So if I had 4 different elements in JSON, it would move through them and then start back at the first after that last duration?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. If you're ever not sure whats going on in your code, just console.log() some data and see where you're at. You should be able to get it to work no problem.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to try this out with other panel types and mess with it. Part of my problem was the JSON was coming back encoded from my result, but this parses it into an actual array I guess

Comment: One issue I'm seeing is that as long as my JSON only has elements for one Page ID then it works but if there are more than that it doesn't, which is why i initially had mine set with a for loop. How could I rectify that? So if the first 2 elements are pageID 93, i would show that content and then after the duration, I would go to elements of the next pageID?

Comment: Just move the DOM selectors to be inside the function thats running inside your setInterval function, so that the dom elements get reselected each time the function runs. You might have to put some more rules inside the function to say `if page === 90, get these elements, else if page === 94 get these other elements`

Comment: Oh that may be the issue, I don't have another function, just the code I posted above

Comment: Ok, so this is technically working but I think there was a slight miscommunication: Currently if there are 4 rows in the JSON, it will show each one after a couple of seconds. What I'm aiming to do is look by the pageID value of the JSON, and if they have the same pageID show all items for it simultaneously. So if the first two elements/content have pageID 93 and the content is "left" and "right", I want to show those simultaneously. Then, after a few seconds, show the next number of elements associated with the next pageID

Comment: Gotcha... It's really hard to process 2 items at the same time, so my suggestion would be to merge any objects that have the same pageID into a single object that represents the entire page, and then has a `content` property with an array of objects for the individual content. Here's a fiddle example. Good luck! 
https://jsfiddle.net/nr37tL9j/